# Can I send multiple requests at one time using Fiddler?

Tags: service, fiddler

Using Fiddler, I want to send multiple requests in one hit, to check the response time from the server, if too many requests are sent at one time. Basically, I want to perform a, kind of, load testing on my service. Is there any way to perform this action? I want to repeat the process of hitting the server, again and again.

Comment: Use JMeter for this, not Fiddler...

Comment: I'm not considering JMeter here. My plan is to do it by using Fiddler. I also found an extension of Fiddler called "stresstimulus". I was going through it but it only allows me to have 3 iterations at one time.

Comment: http://www.stresstimulus.com/ has a free version that allows up to simultaneous 250 VUs (iterations). It is for load testing in Fiddler.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Fiddler, you can repeat a request as many times as you like by hitting SHIFT+R on the selected Web Session. You'll be prompted for a repeat count and then Fiddler will issue the specified number of requests.

Caveat: Having said that, generally speaking, you'd want to use a tool like Telerik Test Studio's Load Test tool for a task like this. Alternatively, you could use Fiddler's Export architecture to generate a script for VS WebTest or Microsoft's free WCAT tool and use those tools to generate the load. You can then run these scripts on multiple machines from multiple networks and generate a more-realistic set of load than you could by simply running on a single client.

Comment: Thanks Eric. But I was assuming that is there any way that I can set a time lag between every iteration. Suppose, I want to send 5 request and each request in x number of seconds. 
Right now, as per your solution, I'm sending X number of requests but I can't set a time lag between every request, so that Request no. 1 hits the server in 3 seconds and Request no 2 hits the server in 10 seconds and so on.

Comment: If you want "think time" within your repeats, you either need to write some script or use one of the other tools I mentioned.

Comment: Does requests be executed in synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: @Mani: I don't really understand what you're asking, but your best bet is to open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I've been load testing with [StresStimulus](http://www.stresstimulus.com/) today. Overall, I'm quite impressed.

It's now a standalone application (it used to be a fiddler extension). There's a 7 day free trial which allows up to 50 virtual users. Also, the setup wizard is great for beginners.

For basic load testing the trial should be fine. Consider upgrading for extensive/professional use.

Comment: @ full_prog_full, as you noted, StresStimulus is now a standalone load testing tool. It also remains to be a Fiddler add-on. 7-day trials issued for 50 VUs can be upgraded to up to 10k VUs per user request.

Comment: @VadimKleyzit Good job with StresStimiuls. The free trial is really easy to run as a beginner to stress testing. Perhaps an idea would be to consider accepting casual donations? I would have donated if the option was available.

Comment: @ full_prog_full, Thanks for your nice comment. Our trials are free to use during the evaluation. Donations are not necessary as we sell commercial licenses. StresStimulus installer also includes a perpetually free scaled-down version with 250 VUs provided as our way of giving back to the community and spreading the word about StresStimulus.