# How to profile MVC4 application, send multiple get requests to Web site for testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache, mono, vmware, esx

ASP.NET MVC4 shopping cart application runs under Debian using Mono, Postgres, Apache and mod_mono in VPS server in virtual hosting with 8 GB RAM.

Sometimes application works slowly.

top and free shows that all memory is used but ESX hypervisor  shows that actually only free parem of memory is used.

Apache access log file contains http GET requests which may cause this.
How to send those get requests to application.

Is there some free tool which and issue list of GET requests to web site automatically to perform stress testing ?
List of requests is text file, every get url is in separate like, it is Apache standard log file format.

Can Fiddler so sometihg similar used to read and send requests from file ?

How to profile this system to find reason of slowness ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine how well your software program responds to various levels of usage, you conduct **load tests**. A load test models the expected usage of a software program by simulating multiple users who access the program at the same time.

**Visual Studio Ultimate** lets you use an unlimited number of virtual users on a local and remote load test run. The virtual users that are used in load tests use multiprocessor architecture. Multiprocessor architecture allows the machine on which the virtual users are installed to use more than one processor. In a load test, the load pattern properties specify how the simulated user load is adjusted during a load test. Visual Studio Ultimate provides **three built-in load patterns**: **constant**, **step**, and **goal-based**. You choose the load pattern and adjust the properties to appropriate levels for your load test goals.

Text taken from: [Testing Performance and Stress Using Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Video tutorial: [Load testing applications in Visual Studio](http://s.ch9.ms/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Load-testing-applications-in-Visual-Studio)

Comment: I'm using free Visual Stution Express 2013 for Web. Production application is running in Apache in Debian. I have part of Apace log file which shows GET requests which probably cause some issue. How to issue those requests to server rapidly and multiple times, which free tool can be used for this ? Can you be more specific, please. I can probably install VS ultimate trial in virtual maschine every time I need to test it, but maybe is there unlimited time free tools available for this ?

Comment: Have you tried googleing "free tool for making multiple get requests"?

Comment: I tried and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101483/can-i-send-multiple-requests-at-one-time-using-fiddler  . This describes Fiddler and WCAT, which is most suitable for my question issue ? http://www.devcurry.com/2010/07/10-free-tools-to-loadstress-test-your.html contains list of them which is most suitable for case is question ? can some tool read apache log file directly and issue get requests from it ?

Comment: Both seem able to achieve what you want. But you should go with Fiddler first given that you seem familiar with it.

Comment: It takes lot of time to convert apache log to fiddler. How to automate this so that apache log can directly used for testing ?